# set value of the textbox equal to the first activated date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Help please,

my code is working, and it is activating only the day of week that i want, but by default the textbox has no value, i want the value of the textbox to be equal to the first date activated in my datepicker

[as u can see in this picture, wednesday is the only day activated, i want the first day activated (5-april-2017) in this case to be the value of the textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aakMs.png)

My code is:

```js
<script>
var j = 3;
$(function() { 
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {        
    var weekDay = parseInt(j, 10);
    if (weekDay === date.getDay()) {
     return [true, '', ''];
    }
    return [false, '', ''];
    }
   });
   // Getter
   var minDate = $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );   
   $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
});
</script>
```

```html
<input type=text name='dtpick' id='datepicker'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question this is what you want:

```
$(function() { 
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {        
    var weekDay = parseInt(j, 10);
    if (weekDay === date.getDay()) {
        return [true, '', ''];
    }
    return [false, '', ''];
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function($) {
   var minDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "minDate");  
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", minDate);
});
```

You just have to pass your minDate variable to the setDate method.

Comment: sorry thats not working, i want the first activated day date to be the value of the textbox

Comment: Sorry my apologies. I forgot to say that this should be inside $(document).ready(function(){});